# Connect a Database hosted in Azure Cloud from AWS Lambda function

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, vpn

I have a requirement where I need to connect to Azure hosted Database from my AWS account Lambda function. I am able to connect to the Database hosted in Azure from my local machine once I connect to company's VPN and whitelisting that IP in Azure side.

Is there a way I can do this from AWS Lambda as well?

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Matthew Leak on Medium has a [great post about how you can achieve this](https://matthewleak.medium.com/aws-lambda-functions-with-a-static-ip-89a3ada0b471); in a nutshell, create a VPC with an Internet Gateway configured with an elastic IP, configure your Lambda function to run within this VPC, then whitelist the assigned elastic IP:

> 1. Create a new VPC to run your code in (or use an existing VPC)
> 2. Create a new Internet Gateway to communicate with the Internet from inside your VPC
> 3. Create a Public Subnet and add a new route to the route table which routes to your Internet Gateway from 0.0.0.0/0
> 4. Create a new Elastic IP address.
> 5. Create a new NAT Gateway and assign it to the Public Subnet and Elastic IP address that you just created.
> 6. Create a Private Subnet and add a new route to the route table which routes to your NAT Gateway from 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: We want to connect to Azure Database from AWS. It's not just to use Lambda function and whitelist the IP in azure.